# Скролинг ListView в ContentDialog

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp, windows-10, windows-10-mobile

C# UWP Windows 10

Есть такого вида ContentDialog:

```
<ContentDialog.Resources>
    <DataTemplate x:Name="MerchantListViewTemplate" x:DataType="data:Merchant">
        <StackPanel VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="20,3">
            <TextBlock Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Text="{x:Bind Title}" Foreground="Black" FontSize="14" Margin="10,0,0,0" TextWrapping="NoWrap"/>
        </StackPanel>
    </DataTemplate>
</ContentDialog.Resources>

<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

    <TextBox Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0"
        HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
             TextChanged="TextBox_TextChanged"/>
    <Button Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1"
        Margin="0,0,0,0" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Background="Transparent" Visibility="{Binding settingsVisibility}">
        <Button.Content>
            <FontIcon Glyph="&#xE109;" Tag="Addnew" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" FontFamily="Segoe MDL2 Assets" FontSize="16"/>
        </Button.Content>
    </Button>
    <Button Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="2"
        HorizontalAlignment="Right" Background="Transparent" Visibility="{Binding settingsVisibility}">
        <Button.Content>
            <FontIcon Glyph="&#xE10A;" Tag="Close" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" FontFamily="Segoe MDL2 Assets" FontSize="16"/>
        </Button.Content>
    </Button>

    <Grid Grid.Row="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="3">
        <ListView x:Name="MerchantList"                
            ItemTemplate="{StaticResource MerchantListViewTemplate}"
            SelectionMode="Single"
            SelectedValue="{Binding currItemId, Mode=TwoWay}"
            SelectedValuePath="Id"
            ShowsScrollingPlaceholders="True">
            <ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
                <Style TargetType="ListViewItem">
                    <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch" />
                    <Setter Property="Margin" Value="0"/>
                    <Setter Property="Padding" Value="0"/>
                </Style>
            </ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
        </ListView>
    </Grid>
</Grid>
```

Само собой ListView не хочет скролиться. Как сделать что бы захотел??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуйте выставить фиксированную высоту у ListView

Comment: Так работает, но мне надо что бы ListView на весь диалог был.

Comment: @SYL, у вас ListView лежит в явно не нужном Grid. переставьте Grid.Row и Grid.ColumnSpan на ListView и удалите родительский Grid. Далее уберите фиксированную высоту у ListView, и все должно стать как вам нужно